# i have a text file in that file have start and end dates how to find the dates by using regex and what is the position of that string in python

Tags: python-3.x

''' From 7 th June , 2012 to August , 2013
Jan - 2015 to Till Date
Mar2010 to Jan - 2015
Oct  2008 to Jan - 2010
Dates : Since May2007 to 2008
Operating System : Windows 2003 '''
''' this is the text file how to find the dates like start and end and postion of that string '''

Comment: [{"start_date": 0, "start_month": 0, "start_year": 0,
                         "start_date_pos": None, "start_month_pos": None, "start_year_position": None,"end_date": 0, "end_month": 0, "end_year": 0,
                         "end_date_pos": None, "end_month_pos": None, "end_year_position": None}]====== output must be like this list of dictionaries

Comment: hii evryone, could you please give me the solution for this one